# How to insert character after second characters in string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I add a character after the second characters in string?

Ex: I want this : `1700` to become this: `17:00`.

Comment: Use string operations, e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

Comment: is this a timestamp? if so, what about 900? is it displayed like 0900?

Answer (score 11):

The simplest way, in my opinion, is using substr to split the string and concatenate the other character in between. This will work no matter the length of the second part:

```
var str = "1700";
str.substr(0,2)+":"+str.substr(2);
```

Comment: I would use `str.substr(0,2)+":"+str.substr(2)`, actually. With `str.substr(2,2)` it'll only work for strings exactly four characters long, which may or may not be okay.

Comment: Yup, I edited it to show that.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
'1700'.match(/../g).join(':')
```

The following regexp accepts 3+ chars:

```
'700'.match(/^(.+)(..)$/).slice(1, 3).join(':') // "7:00"
```

Shortest and probably fastest solution:

```
s[0]+s[1]+":"+s[2]+s[3]
```

Answer (score 2):

this would do the magic:

```
"1700".replace(/(..)$/, ":$1")
```

alternative you can do something like look from behind in substr too like:

```
var string = "1700";
string = string.substr(0, string.length -2) + ":" + string.substr(-2, 2);
```

they both also work on something like: 900 wich will turn into 9:00

the regex and the substr line both do the same. if you want readability i'd consider the regex.

Comment: `"$1:"` as replacement would result in `1700:` since i use `$` for using the regex as lookbehind. the author yet not stated if the input can vary in length

Comment: +1 for the `replace` method, the best so far.

Answer (score 1):

Without using regexp, you can use substr --

```
string = string.substr(0,2) + ":" + string.substr(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring. Consider the following:

```
string1 = "1700";
string2 = ":";
string1 = string1.substring(0,2) + string2 + string1.substring(2);
alert(string1);
```

Comment: `TypeError: .. no method 'insert'`

Comment: Please explain your solution.